# Problem with the payment gateway (Paymentez) remains charging in the purchase

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-14

I have a problem with the integration of the Paymentez payment gateway.
I should mention that I have the payment gateway functional in Odoo 13, and I am migrating to Odoo 14, but when I open the payment popup where the card is entered, it remains as loading and does not allow to enter information.

Check the browser console and I don't have any errors; Warnings only, I tried debugging on the browser side but found no errors either.

[image]

Any ideas to be able to find the problem?

UPDATE:
image correction:

[image]

warnings on the console (browser)

> payment_checkout_stable.min.js?*=1623366558209:1 [Deprecation]
> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
> its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
> check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. (anonymous) @
> payment_checkout_stable.min.js?*=1623366558209:1 Modal.open @
> payment_checkout_stable.min.js?_=1623366558209:1
> _redirectToCheckout @ paymentez.js:200 click @ paymentez.js:33 (anonymous) @ web.assets_common_lazy.js:4552 dispatch @
> web.assets_common_lazy.js:1616 elemData.handle @
> web.assets_common_lazy.js:1602 web.assets_common_lazy.js:1602
> [Violation] 'click' handler took 677ms paymentez.js:185 modal open
> jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4 [Violation] Added synchronous DOM mutation
> listener to a 'DOMNodeInserted' event. Consider using MutationObserver
> to make the page more responsive. add @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4
> (anonymous) @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4 each @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
> each @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2 on @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4 (anonymous)
> @ checkout.js:276 DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load
> content for
> https://ccapi-stg.paymentez.com/static/js/v2/iframeResizer.contentWindow.map:
> HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
> https://tst.kaptcha.com/logo.htm?m=500005&s=b63252570f95454d918ade432dc5868d
> with MIME type text/html. See
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
> details. Image (async) Payment.dataCollector @ payment_2.4.3.min.js:1
> (anonymous) @ checkout.js:282 j @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2 fireWith @
> jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2 ready @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2 J @
> jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2 iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js:formatted:9
> [Violation] 'message' handler took 3792ms recaptcha__es.js:191
> [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 19378ms

Comment: That image is barely readable. Please provide all errors and appropriate warnings in text not an image. More information on how you are implementing the gateway would also be needed.

Comment: @JonP it's fixed!, take the first photo to show the mouse pointer loading! Thxs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the bootstrap css, what you can do is redefine the class

> blockUI

and the tag:

> z-index: 1000;

finally:

```
.blockUI {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
}
```